# Formatted output for dictionary that shows information about files

Tags: python-3.x, file, dictionary

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to write a program that will read a list of text files and returns a dictionary with the `filePaths` and how many `m` in each file.

By searching the internet I came up with the following code:

```py
def readFilesFor_m(filePaths):
    # dictionary for saving no of m's in each file
    dictionary = {}
    
    for filePath in filePaths:
        fileObj = open(filePath, "r");
        fileContent = fileObj.read()
        dictionary[fileObj] = fileContent.count('m');
    fileObj.close()
    return dictionary


fileLists = [
    "H:\\SomeTextFiles\\16.txt",
    "H:\\SomeTextFiles\\Chat.txt",
    "H:\\SomeTextFiles\\zero-m.txt"
]
print(readFilesFor_m(fileLists))
```

The program runs, but the output I'm seeing isn't as simple as I thought it would be (wanted to be):

```py
{<_io.TextIOWrapper name='H:\\SomeTextFiles\\16.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>: 581, 
     <_io.TextIOWrapper name='H:\\SomeTextFiles\\Chat.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>: 20, 
     <_io.TextIOWrapper name='H:\\SomeTextFiles\\zero-m.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>: 0}
```

I don't want those extra things in my dictionary, I just want to see,

```py
{'H:\\SomeTextFiles\\16.txt': 581, 'H:\\SomeTextFiles\\Chat.txt': 20, 'H:\\SomeTextFiles\\zero-m.txt': 0}
```

What do I need to do to achieve that?

Comment: Just replace `dictionary[fileObj]` with `dictionary[filePath]`.

Comment: I found it already, +1

Answer (score 1):

The text you're seeing is a string representation of `fileObj` which you have used as the key in your dictionary. Just use `filePath` instead, since you already have the path as a string.

```
dictionary[filePath] = fileContent.count('m')
```

Also you are opening a new file object in each iteration but only closing it once, outside the loop. It would be better to close inside the loop, or use a `with` block that would handle it for you.

Comment: Good catch about the file closing.

Comment: Updated with file closing inside the loop, how can I improve the code to better standard, say using try-catch block. @shriakhilc

Comment: @abhimanyue, you can start by following the recommendations from [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). `snake_case` instead of `camelCase` for variable names, for example.